# get cell value of removed DataGridView row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My datagridview itemDelete function:

```
this.dgv_items.RowsRemoved += this.dgv_items_itemDelete;

private void dgv_items_itemDelete(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int row = e.RowIndex;
        string name = dgv_items.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        deleteFromDB(name);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

But by the time we reach this code, the row will have been removed, meaning `dgv_items.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value` gets the value if the row next in line.

I want to get the `Cells[0]` value of the removed row, so I can remove the item from the database file as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: BTW, you should remove that try/catch block. If there is a problem, you will never know what it is.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry about the title, really tired. I am aware that the try/catch block may be a problem but this program is for quick personal use so I don't really care atm. But I agree it's bad practice.

Comment: Did you try the [`UserDeletingRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow.aspx) event ? (supports also event cancelation)

Comment: @LuisQuijada Genius.. that worked! Although I can't pick it as an answer like this. Thanks though ;D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could handle the [`UserDeletingRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow.aspx) event instead. Note that it supports event cancelation.

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily save the value of the cell in a variable when you select the row using the RowEnter event:

```
private void dgv_items_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // tempValue is a class var
                tempValue = dgv_items.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Then retrieve the tempValue before deleting.

Comment: Creative, I like it. It probably would have worked but the UserDeletingRow event, as suggested by Luis, was the only logical solution. Thanks though :D

Comment: FYI, it's bad practice to simply display or log `ex.Message`. Use `ex.ToString()` instead, as it displays the full exception plus stack trace and any inner exceptions.