# How to add a certain value using datagrid to update database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview

I'm having problem with regards to update my database when I remove a row/s in my datagrid.

I tried using [RowsRemoved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsremoved(v=vs.110).aspx) event but it returns me an error that there is no value in the row deleted.

So when I try searching I have come to this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513219/get-cell-value-of-removed-datagridview-row), all similar problems I have found so far is by adding or subtracting a certain number (like + 1 or - 1). So I matched the code with my parameters.

```
private void dataGridSales_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + ip + "," + port + "; Database=records; User ID=" + sqlid + "; Password=" + sqlpass + ""))
    {
        conn.Open();
        int addqty = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridSales.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        string part = dataGridSales.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].ToString();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [dbo].[products]
                SET Quantity = [Quantity] + '" + addqty + "' WHERE [Part No.] = '" + part + "'", conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is, it did not update my database. I also tried this in my SQL

```
Quantity = Quantity + '" + addqty + "'
Quantity += '" + addqty + "'
```

Im using SQL Server 2014

This is the value of the addqty and part at the breakpoint
[image]

This are my datagridview columns. ColumnIndex = 5 is where the part value, and RowIndex is the selected row.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have solve the issue. It was a minor mistake that I wasn't checking the syntax correctly (even there are no errors shown).

```
string part = dataGridSales.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].ToString();
```

Forgot to add `.Value`

```
string part = dataGridSales.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Check `addqty` does it contain any value?

Comment: Did you debug the code? Are you getting proper values in `addqty` and `part` variables?

Comment: I will update my question to post a screenshot of the value for addqty and part

Answer (score 0):

```
Quantity = Quantity + '" + addqty + "'
```

You define `addqty` as an int but use it as a string in the SQL. Remove the single quotes to use the value as a number rather than text.

```
Quantity = Quantity + " + addqty + "
```

Comment: that's not the issue ... it should still work .. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d683a/1

Answer (score 0):

try to replace dataGridSales.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() anddataGridSales.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].ToString(); by

```
dataGridSales.SelectedRows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
dataGridSales.SelectedRows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].ToString();
```

Comment: The event doesn't contain a definition for `RowIndex`.